# Как расположить не распределённый список по горизонтали?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

```css
ul.topmenu {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.topmenu li {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-left: 829px;
  display: inline;
  height: 13px;
  width: 416px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.topmenu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right:
}
```

```html
<img id="background1" src="background1.png">
<img id="logo1" src="logo1.png">
<ul class="topmenu">
  <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">work</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение:

```
.topmenu {
width: 100%
}
.topmenu li {
position: relative;
text-align: center;
display: inline;
font-size: 16px;

line-height: 18px;
text-transform: uppercase;
list-style: none;
padding-left: 0px;
margin: 0px;
padding-right: 10px;
}
.topmenu a {
text-decoration: none;
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
border-radius: 4px;
padding: 9px 17px 9px 17px;
transition: .5s linear;
}
.topmenu a:hover {
background-color: rgba(100, 58, 121, 1);
}
#nav1 {
display: block;
position: relative;
margin-top: 70px;
margin-right: 195px;
float: right;
padding-right: 44px;
}
#mainparagraph1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  color: rgba(247, 243, 234, 1);
  font-size: 42px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 239px;
  line-height: 49px;

}
```